# How to select a React Component by ID="" in React (without using ref)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, jsx

I am importing SVG elements into React component, and then rendering them as components.

How do I attach a reference to  React Components that contain SVG elements from within my componentDidMount()?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share the component code so that we can suggest you on how to get the id otherwise it’s difficult to guess

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score -2):

Well, i don't see code example. U can try to use jQuery, when your component render will finish - this is magic stick in many situations. Just type smth like:

```
let element = $('#element_id');
```

And you will get access to its information